Printing formatted strings returned from functions cause error “error: expected error union type, found 'void'”
I'm trying to print formatted strings from function coati and tapir. This is what the program looks like:
const bufPrint = @import("std").fmt.bufPrint;
const print = @import("std").debug.print;
const DefaultPrng = @import("std").rand.DefaultPrng;

fn qr(comptime a: []const u8) !void { print("\n{s}\n", .{a}); }

fn coati(comptime a: []const u8, b: i32) ![]const u8 {
    var buffer: [64]u8 = undefined;
    return try bufPrint(&buffer, "{d}: a {s} number.", .{b, a});
}

fn tapir(comptime a: []const u8) ![]const u8 {
    var buffer: [64]u8 = undefined;
    return try bufPrint(&buffer, "Checked by {s}.", .{a});
}

pub fn main() !void {
    const qa = @constCast(&DefaultPrng.init(0)).random().intRangeAtMost(i32, 0, 59);
    // const qb = qa / 20;

    try qr("Statements.");
    if (qa < 20) {
        const head = try coati("lesser", qa);
        const tail = try tapir("if-else statement");
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{head, tail});
    } else if (qa < 40) {
        const head = try coati("middle", qa);
        const tail = try tapir("if-else statement");
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{head, tail});
    } else {
        const head = try coati("greater", qa);
        const tail = try tapir("if-else statement");
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{head, tail});
    }
}

For some reasons, when I compile it, there's an error at line try print("{s} {s}\n", .{head, tail}); with the following message:
error: expected error union type, found 'void'
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{head, tail});
            ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
referenced by:
    callMain: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\zig\tools\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0\lib\std\start.zig:511:32
    WinStartup: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\zig\tools\zig-windows-x86_64-0.12.0\lib\std\start.zig:350:45
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces

It seems to me that the strings in coati and tapir failed to be allocated, but I can't figure out where I got wrong.
I tried to pass the buffer into coati and tapir as suggested here, but it still gives the same error. Here's the code now:
const bufPrint = @import("std").fmt.bufPrint;
const print = @import("std").debug.print;
const DefaultPrng = @import("std").rand.DefaultPrng;

fn qr(comptime a: []const u8) !void { print("\n{s}\n", .{a}); }

fn coati(comptime a: []const u8, b: i32, c: []u8) ![]const u8 {
    return try bufPrint(c, "{d}: a {s} number.", .{b, a});
}

fn tapir(comptime a: []const u8, c: []u8) ![]const u8 {
    return try bufPrint(c, "Checked by {s}.", .{a});
}

pub fn main() !void {
    const qa = @constCast(&DefaultPrng.init(0))
        .random()
        .intRangeAtMost(i32, 0, 59);

    try qr("Statements.");
    if (qa < 20) {
        var kant: [64]u8 = undefined;
        const face = try coati("lesser", qa, &kant);
        const butt = try tapir("if-else statement", &kant);
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{face, butt});
    } else if (qa < 40) {
        var kant: [64]u8 = undefined;
        const face = try coati("middle", qa, &kant);
        const butt = try tapir("if-else statement", &kant);
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{face, butt});
    } else {
        var kant: [64]u8 = undefined;
        const face = try coati("greater", qa, &kant);
        const butt = try tapir("if-else statement", &kant);
        try print("{s} {s}\n", .{face, butt});
    }
}


I'll repeat: the compiler tells you that print doesn't return an error, so you don't need to use try on the result.

First, the compiler tells you that print doesn't return an error, so you don't need to use try on the result.
Second, the strings are indeed "failed to be allocated". You're making the classic newbie mistake of returning a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior. There are many other questions with the same problem.
